# Awesomium WebControl not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, awesomium

Sorry if this sounds a little noobish, but I just installed Awesomium SDK, added references to the project, and I can't find the "WebControl" in the ToolBox. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is run the setup to uninstall and reinstall it in the assembly folder.

http://wiki.awesomium.net/getting-started/setting-up-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help, go to your project properties and check the target framework.It should be .Net Framework 4 client profile or above

Answer (score 0):

You should create WebView, add it to form, set it **location and size** and set source URI!
try to include namespaces:

```
using Awesomium;
using Awesomium.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Core;

static class Program {

    static Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    static Form fm = new Form {};
    static WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
    //private static WebView wv;
    static WebControl wc = new WebControl{Visible = true};
    //static WebView wv;// = new WebView(fm.Handle);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //f1.ShowDialog();  return;

        wc.ViewType = WebViewType.Window;
        wc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
        wc.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000,1000);
        fm.Controls.Add(wc);
        //wv = new WebView(fm.Handle);
        //fm.Controls.Add(wv.con);
        wc.Source = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com");
        Task k = new Task(delegate {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            try {
                fm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                    try {

                        MessageBox.Show(wc.Source.ToString());

                    } catch {
                        MessageBox.Show("2");
                    }

                }));
            } catch {
                MessageBox.Show("1");
            }

        });
        k.Start();
        fm.ShowDialog();
    }//main
```